# How to extract a specific text from a vector that is separated with multiple commas in R

Tags: r, extract

This is my first post and I am relatively new to R world so I hope I post my question respectfully to the website. I search for this but I could not come up with something efficient.

I have a column that has such a structure:

```
df$col1 <- c("book, pencil,eraser,pen", "book,pen", "music,art,sport", "apple, banana, kiwi, watermelon", "Earth, Mars, Jupiter").
```

what I would like to do is that I would like to create a new column that is going to be built based on certain elements of the `col1`.

If the first cell has 2 commas, then I would like to extract the element between the first and the second comma and write it to the first cell in the new column. If the next cell has 3 commas, then I would like to extract the element between the second and third comma and write it to the second cell in the new column and so on.

As can be seen from the example of col1, I have cells not in order of the number of commas so sometimes a three-comma-separated cell structure might occur again in the following cells. I need to account for that too.

Could you please help me in this regard?

Your help is much appreciated in advance!

Comment: Include what you expect. eg do you want `eraser, pen, art, kiwi, Mars`? Include what you want in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the following?

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 mutate(col2 = str_split(col1, "\\s*,\\s*") %>%
   map_chr(~ if (length(.x) %in% 1:2) {.x[length(.x)]} 
      else {.x[length(.x) - 1]}))

#>                              col1   col2
#> 1         book, pencil,eraser,pen eraser
#> 2                        book,pen    pen
#> 3                 music,art,sport    art
#> 4 apple, banana, kiwi, watermelon   kiwi
#> 5            Earth, Mars, Jupiter   Mars
```

Comment: I have tried this but this is not giving me the extract of a certain cell. What I would like to achieve is that I would like to get, let's say, the third element (eraser in the case of the first cell) in a cell that is separated with three commas (or nth element in a cell which is separated with n-1 commas). What you provide splits, it does not extract I guess but I might be wrong :)

Comment: Just try the following: `c("book, pencil,eraser,pen") %>% 
  str_split("\\s*,\\s*") %>% unlist %>% .[3] `.

Comment: I have just updated my solution, which now does what you are wanting, I guess.

Comment: That works very well, Thank you very much:) Although this is useful, I have this issue with many cells which has the same structure. What I want to do is that I would like to extract certain elements from comma-separated values and create a column with these extracts depending on the number of commas that each cell has (for example, if the cell has 1 comma, then extract only the left element, if two elements, then extract the middle element, if three then the 3rd element and if 4 command, then again 3rd element). Is there an efficient way that you can think of?

Comment: I think you should first define clearly the rule of extraction: Which element should be extracted when there is `n` elements? Define that clearly, and we will be able to help you.

Comment: Okay then let me edit the post first. I got it all mixed up. I am sorry

Comment: I am not sure whether my new solution corresponds to what you are wanting.

Comment: That's it, Paul. Thank you so so much! This is what I am looking for. I really appreciate your time and patience! Have a great day/weekend!

Comment: From your explanation I thought you needed eraser, _book_, art as col2? As you said: _for example, if the cell has 1 comma, then extract only the left element_

Answer (score 1):

Here's a straightforward regex solution to extract the pre-ultimate word into a new column:

```
df %>%
  mutate(col2 = str_extract(col1, "\\w+(?=,[^,]+$)"))
                             col1   col2
1         book, pencil,eraser,pen eraser
2                        book,pen   book
3                 music,art,sport    art
4 apple, banana, kiwi, watermelon   kiwi
5            Earth, Mars, Jupiter   Mars
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 =c("book,pencil,eraser,pen", "book,pen", "music,art,sport"))
```

Comment: Your regex solution helps me to a great extent! Thank you so much!

Comment: If it helps please upvote. But aren't you looking to create a new column that **flexibly** extracts the pre-ultimate word in `col1`?

Comment: I will upvote for sure. I am sorry I forgot. I am looking for creating a new column but for the time being, I am trying to create that column by myself and if someone provides a solution faster than me, I would appreciate that :) If I find the solution, then I will post it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `strsplit`. I this case `n` is 3.

```
df$col1 <- c("book, pencil,eraser,pen", "book,pen", "music,art,sport")
strsplit(df$col1, ',')[[1]][3]

[1] "eraser"
```

**EDIT**
If I understand your question correctly, you could do something like this:

```
 df <- data.frame(col1 =c("book,pencil,eraser,pen", "book,pen", "music,art,sport"), stringsAsFactors = F)
 df$col2 <- lapply(df$col1, FUN = function(x) {strsplit(x, ",")[[1]][stringr::str_count(x, ",")]})
 df
                    col1   col2
1 book,pencil,eraser,pen eraser
2               book,pen   book
3        music,art,sport    art
```

Comment: This is what I would like to get, thank you very much. But the issue is that there are many cells that have more than 2 commas. In this case, your indexation will be specific to the first cell. Is there a way that I can extract the nth element from many cells that have more than two commas (and eventually assign them to a column)?

Comment: Ah, I put a possible solution for that in the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time to think of this. This also works :)